# Setting debug_mode with Measurement Protocol (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Can't find a way to set the **debug_mode** parameter using **Measurement Protocol 4**.
Tried to put it everywhere (and naming it all i can think of) but without luck :)
Documentation is still very light and doesn't mention the debug_mode.
With web/js and GA4 it works fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Weird. Suddenly the debug mode started to work with code I'm 100% sure didn't work before.

Adding the parameter `"debug_mode": true` to the measurement protocol request will make it show up in Analytics' DebugView.

Sample json payload that works:

```json
{
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY",
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "page_view",
      "params": {
        "page_location": "...",
        "page_path": "...",
        "page_title": "...",
        "debug_mode": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For completeness sake: `"params": {"x-ga-system_properties": {"dbg": "1"}}` also works

Comment: Sorry about that, `x-ga-system_properties` only seems to work if it is going to a server-side GTM container, not directly to GA4

Comment: I've been using your above example, and for a long time, I thought it was incorrect or had something wrong because I couldn't see it show in DebugView.

Eventually, I checked my actual analytics and saw that the page_view events were showing, so my assumption is DebugView is just buggy.

Comment: Apparently there is a caveat: the `client_id` needs to be already known to GA4. 
 See here for more details > https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/debugview-with-ga4-measurement-protocol/

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answers of @DalmTo and @bang - I wasn't seeing events I was sending over the Measurement Protocol show up in our GA4 Debug View. The root cause in my case was that the Measurement Protocol expects a funky format for the `user_properties`, but the following steps should help others debug other problems as well.

Steps I took to resolve:

1. Add the `debug_mode: true` field to individual event params [as described in @bang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65100157/971091)
2. Use the `/debug/mp` endpoint [as described in @DalmTo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094795/971091) - this pointed me towards the errors in my `user_properties` format

Regarding the `user_properties` field, I was sending something along these lines:

```
{
  "client_id": "XXX.XXX",
  "user_id": "YYY",
  "user_properties": {
    "property_a": "value_a",
    "property_b": "value_b"
  },
  "events": ...
}
```

Turns out GA4 / Measurement Protocol expect something like this:

```
{
  "client_id": "XXX.XXX",
  "user_id": "YYY",
  "user_properties": {
    "property_a": { "value": "value_a" },
    "property_b": { "value": "value_b" }
  },
  "events": ...
}
```

At the time of writing, the only way to figure this out is to carefully check out the example [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/user-properties?client_type=gtag).

Answer (score 0):

The measurment protocol for ga4 has two endpoints just like the measurment protocol for the old Google anlaytics

- Measurement Protocol  /mp/collect
- Measurement Protocol Validation Server    /debug/mp/collect

So if you [send a event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events) to it will be sent to Google anlaytics ga4

```
POST /mp/collect HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google-analytics.com

<payload_data>
```

So if you send a event to it will be sent to [debug endpoint](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/validating-events) for Google anlaytics ga4

```
POST /debug/mp/collect HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google-analytics.com

<payload_data>
```

Comment: Yes, that I'm aware of but is not what I'm looking for. I want to append the debug_mode parameter to a request that will cause analyitcs to register the event but filter it to the DebugView. The /debug/mp/collect will only validate the request not register it at all in analytics.  Link to the more info about debug_mode: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7201382?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a timestamp in a param named `engagement_time_msec`.

```
{
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY",
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "xxx",
      "params": {
        ...
        "debug_mode": true,
        "engagement_time_msec": <TIMESTAMP>
      }
    }
  ]
}
```